# How to use @Async and @Transactional for rolling back in multi threading?

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot, hibernate, exception

My requirement is to rollback all the transactions in a multi threaded system
if one of the thread encounters exception.

```
package com.demo.multithread; 

@Repository
@Configuration
public class DemoService {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    @Bean
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = {Exception.class,Error.class})
    public void callProcedure()
    {
        StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("MyProcedure");
        query.execute();
    }
}
```

Below is how I am using Async.

```
package com.demo.multithread; 

@Repository
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class DemoDAO 
{
@Autowired
public DemoService demoService;

@Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public ExecutorService executorService() 
    {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(10);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("myThread-");
        executor.initialize();
        System.out.println("Returning from executor service");
        return executor.getThreadPoolExecutor();
    }

@Async(value ="threadPoolTaskExecutor")
     public void asyncMethodWithConfiguredExecutor() throws InterruptedException 
     {
        System.out.println("Thread ID~" + Thread.currentThread().getId()+ " is running and thread name is ~"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        demoService.callProcedure();
     }
}
```

**Issue is :**

1. Multi threading is not happening.
2. Just 1 thread is getting created on Startup.
3. If I use @Async and @Transactional together (which I shouldn't) then
   multithreading happens.  But rollback do not work.

Answer (score 0):

When the @Async method starts it runs on a new thread that’s the reason @Transaction is not working. You can’t do rollback by the @Async method call but without async calls, you can do the rollback.